How to invoke REST api using VBA script
Dim WHTTP As Object
Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")    

mainUrl = "https://googlesample.api.google/okta"
myuser = "myluckyuser"
mypass = "myluckypassword"

strAutheticate = "username=" & myuser & "& password=" & mypass
WHTTP.Open "POST", mainUrl, False
'WHTTP.setRequestHeader "apikey", "[Token]"
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
WHTTP.send strAutheticate

Dim response As String

??? How to I receive the token here ????

I am trying to invoke the API using REST and get the token.
so should return "access_token" : "blah134hao9u098-098-09";

Always helps to share a URL to the Help pages for the specific API you're trying to call.

whttp.responseText? you need to write a wait-loop though.

Dim tokenHTTP As Object
Set tokenHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Dim tokenJSON As String
Dim tokenURL As String
Dim accessToken As String
tokenURL = "https://googlesample.api.google/okta"
tokenHTTP.Open "POST", tokenURL, True
tokenHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
tokenHTTP.setRequestHeader "username", "myusername"
tokenHTTP.setRequestHeader "password", "mypassword"

tokenHTTP.send (tokenURL)
tokenJSON = tokenHTTP.responseText 


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
